# polarvector to edge of rectangle

Tags: coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Say I got a rectangle with its middle coordinates $(x_m,y_m)$ inline with the coordinate grid with a corner in $(x_c,y_c)$. What's the distance from $(x_m,y_m)$ to the rectangle edge at angle $a$?

[Explanatory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z26Mz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find at what angles the corners are. You have first corner at $(x_m,y_m)$, so say the angle is $\beta_1$, such as $$\tan\beta_1=\frac{y_m-y_c}{x_m-x_c}$$ You can get the other angles by symmetry: $\beta_2=180^\circ-\beta_1$, $\beta_3=180^\circ+\beta_1$, $\beta_4=360^\circ-\beta_1$. Now you have two cases:

- *Case 1*: $0^\circ\le \alpha\lt\beta_1$ or $\beta_2\le\alpha\lt\beta_3$ or $\beta_4\le\alpha\lt 360^\circ$
- *Case 2*: $\beta_1\le\alpha\lt\beta_2$ or $\beta_3\le\alpha\lt\beta_4$

In the first case you intersect one of the vertical sides, in the second you intersect the top or bottom. For *Case 1*, you know the horizontal length ($x_c-x_m$), for *Case 2* you know the vertical length ($y_m-y_c$)